# Jquery datepicker defaultDate php isset check

Tags: php, jquery-ui, xhtml

I'm coding a SQL query to look for events in a database.
I use php to get the data from a html form and I'm using different preset queries for various situations, one of which is:

- the user didn't give a specific time using the jquery datepicker; if
  so, I use php date() function to get today's date, and work with it; if
  not, I just use the from-to dates that the user selected.

Here's the problem: I'm using php to validate what the user gives as specific dates.

```
$fechaini = $_POST['fechaini'];
$fechafin = $_POST['fechafin'];
//cheking bars
if(isset($fechaini)){
     echo "fechaini: ".$fechaini;
   }
if(isset($fechafin)){
     echo "fechafin: ".$fechafin;
   }
```

This works fine but if the user didn't give any specific date (meaning he leaves it blank), php still echoes this output:

```
fechaini:
fechafin:
```

I need that if the user leaves the date inputs blank it prints nothing, allowing me to filter these inputs to build my queries without 'em.

***Here is the site for you to see what happens:***
http://sistemahorarios.no-ip.org/sh/consultas4.php
it will be avalaible for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to var_dump() the POST vars, I believe even if the user didn't select a date that field will still come back `string(0) ''`, so I would do this to check:

```
 if('' !== $fechaini){
     echo "fechaini: ".$fechaini;
   }
   if('' !== $fechafin){
     echo "fechafin: ".$fechafin;
   }
```

Comment: thanks!!!
it does the job, after you give your answer i check the php manual for the isset() function and guess what? , the JQ datepicker send a null as default, but isset() reads it as string(0) ''.
I didn't know about the var_dump() it helps me out a lot.**PD: Your code works great.**